# Excel - VBA: does Worksheet.Range.Delete have a columns number limitation?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with a simple line that deletes some targeted columns. I used such a line plenty of times but it is the first time that I got an error on it. The fact is it's a lot of columns, too much it seems, because when I delete some of them in the quotes (approximately 10), I don't have an error anymore. So does it mean that VBA have a limit of the number of columns in a range?

```
MyWorksheet.Range("Q:Q,R:R,S:S,T:T,U:U,V:V,W:W,X:X,Y:Y,Z:Z,AA:AA,AB:AB,AC:AC,AD:AD,AE:AE,AF:AF,AG:AG,AH:AH,AJ:AJ,AL:AL,AN:AN,AP:AP,AR:AR,AT:AT,AV:AV,AX:AX,AZ:AZ,BB:BB,BD:BD,BH:BH,BJ:BJ,BL:BL,BN:BN,BP:BP,BR:BR,BT:BT,BV:BV,BX:BX,BZ:BZ,CB:CB,CF:CF,CH:CH,CJ:CJ,CN:CN,CP:CP,CR:CR,CT:CT").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Those columns come from a list of string, so I am aware that I could do a For loop and delete one by one.

I'm new to Stack Overflow and not an English native so sorry if I did any mistakes.

EDIT :

Originally, I use a dictionary to store some specific columns, then I aggregate the dictionary items with some comas and put the variable in my range.

```
For i = 1 To ColToDeleteArray.Count
    If ColToDeleteArray.Exists(i) Then
        ColToDeleteString = ColToDeleteString & ColToDeleteArray(i) & ":" & ColToDeleteArray(i) & ","
    End If
Next i

ColToDeleteString = Left(ColToDeleteString, Len(ColToDeleteString) - 1)
MyWorksheet.Range(ColToDeleteString).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: You can combine your arguments, eg `Q:Z`, this may help - `Range("Q:AH,AJ:AJ,AL:AL,AN:AN,AP:AP,AR:AR,AT:AT,AV:AV,AX:AX,AZ:AZ,BB:BB,BD:BD,BH:BH,BJ:BJ,BL:BL,BN:BN,BP:BP,BR:BR,BT:BT,BV:BV,BX:BX,BZ:BZ,CB:CB,CF:CF,CH:CH,CJ:CJ,CN:CN,CP:CP,CR:CR,CT:CT").Delete` seems to be working for me

Comment: Yes, I tried but still does not work. Plus, those columns are from a string I aggregated (originally from a list) wih commas, so it is hard to combine the columns.

Comment: @Chris how is that string generated? Please add this to your question.

Comment: There's no limit to number of columns you can delete - but you've probably reached a 256 character limit in the string value - yours is slightly more - you can probably do it in two segments

Comment: @dbmitch I haven't thought of that. You are 100% right, thanks a lot!

Comment: or better just use the [Application.Union Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel) to combine the ranges in the loop directly instead of writing that string.

Comment: If you go in two segments start deleting from right to left vs left to right. Your columns will be completely changed if you go left to right after the shift to the left. If you go backwards you can avoid having to rematch your columns to be deleted

Comment: @Peh yes, I'll do that for sure

Comment: @urdearboy I am very aware of that issue as I did the mistake before!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub hfsjdfh()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    s = "Q:Q,R:R,S:S,T:T,U:U,V:V,W:W,X:X,Y:Y,Z:Z,AA:AA,AB:AB,AC:AC,AD:AD,AE:AE,AF:AF,AG:AG,AH:AH,AJ:AJ,AL:AL,AN:AN,AP:AP,AR:AR,AT:AT,AV:AV,AX:AX,AZ:AZ,BB:BB,BD:BD,BH:BH,BJ:BJ,BL:BL,BN:BN,BP:BP,BR:BR,BT:BT,BV:BV,BX:BX,BZ:BZ,CB:CB,CF:CF,CH:CH,CJ:CJ,CN:CN,CP:CP,CR:CR,CT:CT"
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    For Each a In arr
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Set r = Range(a)
        Else
            Set r = Union(r, Range(a))
        End If
    Next a
    MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

- So even if the string is too long for the `Range` object to handle, it can still be used via `Union()`.
- Once the range has been created, its address is somewhat compact compared to the original string.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider iterating over your `ColToDeleteArray` in reverse and deleting columns individually.

```
For i = ColToDeleteArray.count To 1 Step -1
    If ColToDeleteArray.Exists(i) Then
        Range(ColToDeleteArray(i) & ":" & ColToDeleteArray(i)).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
Next i
```

Oh, and to answer the titular question directly, no, there is no limit on how many columns may be deleted with the `range.delete` command. Eg

```
[A:XFD].Delete
```

will delete all of the columns (Excel 2007-2016)

Comment: Note that you don't need consecutive columns for Gary's approach. This will also work for non-consecutive columns.

Comment: It is exactly what I was doing the first time but I wanted to delete in a "one-liner" way without a for loop (even if I do one to create the string before). I was just wondering. Thanks a lot tho!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ well huh, I suppose that you are correct - for some reason I had it in my head that one would need to use `Range(r.address).Delete` and that that could cause some issues - but you can just use `r.Delete` and avoid all that - my bad